# How to parse the section of the following file in Python?

Tags: python, parsing, python-3.x

I have a file like this:

```
Hi:
    fdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfdfdsfdsfdsfsdfdsfsdfdsfsdfdsfds
    fdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfsfdsfdsfsdfsdfsdfsdffdsfdsfds
    Exampples:

    >>fdsfds
    >>ok

    This is it.

Hello:
    fdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfsd
    fdsfdsfdsfdsfds
    fdsfdsfsd
```

The section of `Hi` is from `fds...` to `This is it.` The section of `Hello` is from `fds..` to `fds..`
I want to get only the section of all the headings. I thought of the following approach:

`Start from :` and then look upto `\n\n` which will give me the section respectively. But this won't because the section itself can have the same format. I don't want to do this using `regex` or `Configparser`. I am looking for simple parsing. How to tackle this problem?

Comment: So, how can I recognize when a new section starts?

Comment: There is a single line break however on examples there's double.

Comment: But if single line breaks also appear inside of the section, you can't really tell if a new section starts or not.

Comment: Maybe line ending with colon ?

Comment: May be the combination will work --> `:\n` because on examples there would be `:\n\n`

Comment: It is really [very easy](http://regex101.com/r/hP7qT3) with a regex...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could search for lines not starting with five spaces:

```
tab = "     " # five spaces
with open('input.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.startswith(tab):
            print line
```

Comment: It prints nothing. And I don't have write access to the input file.

Comment: Please see the edited question. The section have four or five spaces. However, when I read the file, I don't see `\t`

Comment: Well this prints everything.

Comment: well, is there spaces or tabs ? simply replace the \t in the code here by what the line are starting with.

Comment: It turns out there are five spaces. However, if I do `if not line.startswith(tab)` it prints the header only thus `if line.startswith(tab)` worked.

Comment: ok then last edit should work ^^

Comment: I would recommend using `with open('input.txt', 'r') as f:` rather than `f = open(...)` and `f.close()` as its cleaner and **significantly** less prone to errors.

Answer (score 0):

This is really easy with a regex:

```
txt='''\
Hi:
    fdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfdfdsfdsfdsfsdfdsfsdfdsfsdfdsfds
    fdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfsfdsfdsfsdfsdfsdfsdffdsfdsfds
    Exampples:

    >>fdsfds
    >>ok

    This is it.

Hello:
    fdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfsd
    fdsfdsfdsfdsfds
    fdsfdsfsd'''

import re

print(re.findall(r'^(\w+:.*?)(?=^\w+:|\Z)', txt, re.S | re.M))
```

Prints:

```
['Hi:\n    fdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfdfdsfdsfdsfsdfdsfsdfdsfsdfdsfds\n    fdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfsfdsfdsfsdfsdfsdfsdffdsfdsfds\n    Exampples:\n\n    >>fdsfds\n    >>ok\n\n    This is it.\n\n', 'Hello:\n    fdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfsd\n    fdsfdsfdsfdsfds\n    fdsfdsfsd']
```